# "Come of a royal family" vs. "comes from a royal family"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, collocation

Is it correct to say "She comes of a royal family"? Or should it be "She comes from a royal family"?

Both sound correct to me. Could someone explain?

Comment: _Comes of_ is a completely archaic expression, other than the idiom _That's what comes of (doing something)_.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say something like "She comes from royalty"?

Answer (score 4):

My intuition is that the construction with *of* collocates more readily with the verb *be* rather than the verb *come*, as in, for example, ‘She is of royal blood.’ For that reason, ‘She comes from a royal family’ seems to me to be more likely.

Comment: Agree entirely. “She comes of a royal family” is utterly ungrammatical to me.